# pymongo find query on multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a query that looks like this:

```
    data = self.db.find({"$and" : [
                                      {
                                          "loc": {
                                              "$within": {
                                                  "$box": [
                                                      [
                                                          minX,
                                                          minY
                                                      ],
                                                      [
                                                          maxX,
                                                          maxY
                                                      ]
                                                  ]
                                              }
                                          }
                                      },
                                       {
                                           "dateTime" : {
                                                    "$gt" : minTimeStamp,
                                                    "$lt" : maxTimeStamp
                                           }
                                       }
                                ]
                        })
```

however this returns a count of 0 if I do the query:

```
self.db.find({"loc": {"$within": {"$box": [[minX, minY], [maxX, maxY]]}}})
```

I recieve data data and some of this data is within the timestamps! Am I doing something wrong? can anyone shed some light on this situation?

Many thanks

Comment: more brackets got added to the syntax when sumeet tried to reindent it. (so what you currently see up there is wrong) I'm going fix that now  - update it now shows the correct amount of brackets

Comment: You shouldn't need the $and condition as you are not comparing different conditions on the same field, so the "dateTime" comparison is just another argument. Remove the wrapping and as well as the braces `{}` around each statement. But you problem is likely with the values to are passing in for the date comparison. Run that by itself to see.